# Attempting to combine JSON responses

Tags: python, json, list

I am attempting to call multiple pages of an API and combine their responses.

```py
# function to get return data from all pages
def getplayerdata(pages, url):
    print("Fetching " + str(pages) + " pages.")
    # create blank playerdata object
    playerdata = {"listings": []}
    for x in range(pages):
        currentPageNum = x+1
        currentPageURL = url + str(currentPageNum)
        print("Getting data from: " + currentPageURL)
        dataFetch = getpagedata(currentPageURL)
        newPlayerData = dataFetch['listings']
        playerdata["listings"].append(newPlayerData)
    return playerdata
```

It seems like I am 95% of the way there. The issue is that my JSON output isn't formatted perfectly. Right now the output is showing as:

```py
"listings": [
    [
        {data from page one}
    ]
    [
        {data from page two}
    ]
]
```

I am looking for:

```py
"listings": [
    {data from page one},
    {data from page two}
]
```

Any ideas? Am I doing something completely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```py
playerdata["listings"].append(newPlayerData)
```

to

```py
playerdata["listings"].extend(newPlayerData)
```

You want to add the *elements* of `newPlayerData` to the `playerdata["listings"]` list, *not* the `newPlayerData` list itself.